# OpenDJ - What happens when the total db-cache-percent exceeds 100?

Tags: ldap, opendj

I am using open DJ version 2.4.4 and have many backends configured. Each backend is created with the default db-cache-percent of 10. The total number of backends configured exceeds 10. This implies that the total db-cache-percent exceeds 100. The setup so far has not faced any problem with lesser LDAP read frequency.But in general what kind of impact this would have on the heap and process memory? 
Currently I have configured the max heap as 1G (default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sum of budgeted memory exceeds the max heap size of the server, there is a chance that the server will run out of memory and exit. When and how fast depends on the size of the database and the access patterns.

It is possible to change the default size of database cache, and even set it to specific size rather than a percentage of the overall heap size.

Comment: Thanks, I have not so far run into out of memory issues. But the response times for the same queries increases over a period of time. Not sure whether because of frequent GC.